# The latest schema for Azure Resource Manager Template Language?

Tags: azure, azure-management, azure-management-api, azure-resource-manager

Where can I find which schema is the latest one for the [Azure Resource Manager Template Language](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/)?

*Please note, that I am not asking for the latest schema, but where I can find which is the latest schema. This is so I can continue to use the latest one in the future as well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the oficial GitHub repo

https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/tree/master/schemas